# How to use jQuery to count the number of children in a single block when multiple instances of the target class are on the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a couple of blocks on a page that list content such as `Related Blog Posts` & `Related Articles`.

Those blocks are coded to return all results. But to keep the lists from being too long I defaulted the list to show only 3 items and have worked in a "show more" button that when clicked triggers an accordion effect to show the remaining items if there are any.

The problem I am having is the show more buttons are displaying even if the block doesn't have more than 3 items. It appears that `size()` is counting the total children of both blocks, not each block individually.

Of course I could target 2 unique selectors and get it working. However I would like this script to be reusable without having to always add a new selector every time I need another accordion block.

The way I have it now, whenever you want to apply an accordion effect to a block all you have to do is add a class of "accordion" to the outer wrapper on any block that contains an HTML list.

Here's my code.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        /**
         * Define variables
         */
        var parentSelector = $('.block-views .accordion ul'),
    controlsHTML = $('<div class="show-more"><button>Show More</button></div>'),
    count = $(parentSelector).children().size();

        /**
         * Wrap all items we want to show/hide except for the first 3
         */
        $(parentSelector).children().not(':nth-child(1), :nth-child(2), :nth-child(3)').wrapAll('<div class="slide-content" />');

        /**
         * Hide content that should be hidden by default
         */
        $('.slide-content').hide();

    /**
     * Insert open/close button if there are more than three items in list
     */
    if (count > 3) {
    $(controlsHTML).insertAfter(parentSelector);
    }

        /**
         * Build the expanding content container and attach it to a click event
         */
        $(".show-more button").toggle(
            function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('collapse');
                $(this).text("Show Less");
                $(this).parents('.item-list').find('.slide-content').slideDown();
            },
            function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('collapse');
                $(this).text("Show More");
                $(this).parents('.item-list').find('.slide-content').slideUp();
            }
        );
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You should use `length`, not `size()`, and you need an `each()` to go with that!

Comment: While `.size()` will give you the same result as `.length`. `length` is preferred over `size()` as it saves on an extra function call as per documentation: http://api.jquery.com/size/. Regardless, we would need the actual HTML which is rendered on your page to determine why the count is incorrect. Your selectors should propably consider a specific scope which is hard to recommend without the rendered HTML.

Comment: @adeneo: Thank you, I fixed that. That was a typo :) Ment to say `length` not `length()`.

Comment: As @adeneo said, you need an `.each()` to iterate through each of the parent selectors. I think that the `.length/.size()` is returning the last element here `count = $(parentSelector).children().size();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate thru the accordions and check the length of each one:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() { 

        $('.block-views .accordion ul').each(function(i,elm) {
            var ctrl = $('<div class="show-more"><button>Show More</button></div>'),
                count = $(this).children().length;
            if (count > 3) {
                $(this).after(ctrl);
            }
        });

        $(".show-more button").data('state', true).on('click', function () {
            var state = $(this).data('state');

            $(this).toggleClass('collapse').text("Show "+(state?'Less':'More'));
                   .parents('.item-list').find('.slide-content').slideToggle().data('state' !state);
        });
    });
}(jQuery));​
```

Also note that toggle used that way is deprecated as well!

Comment: Awesome, You Rock adeneo! Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: And thank you to the others for jumping in and providing some help. Was racking my brain trying all sorts of other methods such as using "THIS". I'll need to go school up on each().